# CLAPACK with cmake on ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, cmake

I'm trying to install something using `cmake`.

```
sudo cmake ~/Repositories/siconos/
-- Checking to see if CXX compiler accepts flag -D__aligned__=ignored
-- Checking to see if CXX compiler accepts flag -D__aligned__=ignored - yes
-- Performing Test C_HAVE_-D__aligned__=ignored
-- Performing Test C_HAVE_-D__aligned__=ignored - Success
-- Performing Test C_HAVE_-std=c99
-- Performing Test C_HAVE_-std=c99 - Success
-- Found Python executable: /usr/bin/python
-- Found Python library: /usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so
-- Python version is : 2.7.12
-- Python include dir is : /usr/include/python2.7
-- Python Site package dir is : /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

-- Compilation with required package BLAS version 
-- Lapack libraries have been found : /usr/lib/liblapack.so;/usr/lib/libblas.so. We now turn to headers.
-- Found a library with LAPACK API (generic).
    Lapack libraries : /usr/lib/liblapack.so;/usr/lib/libblas.so.
    Lapack headers : clapack.h in LAPACK_INCLUDE_DIRS-NOTFOUND.
-- Compilation with required package LAPACK version 
CMake Error at cmake/siconos_find_common_dep.cmake:15 (message):
  cannot find lapack include directories
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:88 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

As my LTS has no apt-get support of `CLAPACK`, I have compiled `CLAPACK` following [this link](https://mesot.swisspowered.net/site/software/clapack-on-linux/) and moved the resulting file to

```
ls /usr/include/liblapack.a 
/usr/include/liblapack.a
```

and have added the followign to `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(CLAPACK_DIR /usr/include/liblapack.a)
```

What else do I have to do?

Comment: `/usr/include` should only contain header files (like `clapack.h`) - not libraries themselves

Comment: The library should go to `/usr/lib`, but your `cmake` only seems to look for shared objects, so you probably need to change the `Makefile` you use to build `clapack` to dynamic linking.